# Android - View resource is null inside an event on a fragment in a PageViewer

Tags: android, null, resources, fragment

i've got some trouble with PageViewer, i've searched a lot in the other questions, but it seems that no one fall in my same trouble, so i'm here to ask to the experts what i'm doing wrong.

The problem is this:

I can't figure out inflating the layout inside an event, this is the code:

```
    // onCreateView :
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // fragment not when container null
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // inflate view from layout
    View view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doorsway_lay, container, false);
    // get button reference
    /*
     * btnWrite = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btWrite); // set button
     * listener to trigger activity listener btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new
     * View.OnClickListener() {
     * 
     * @Override public void onClick(View v) {
     * pageListener.onPage1("Page 1 to"); } }); // update text TextView tv =
     * (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvText1); tv.setText(ptext);
     */
    View imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.clickZones);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            View view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doorsway_lay, container, false);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                try {
                    ImageView newView = ((ImageView) v);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) newView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
                    newView.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
                    float[] touchPoint = new float[] { event.getX(),
                            event.getY() };
                    inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);
                    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) touchPoint[0],
                            (int) touchPoint[1]);
                    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
                    if (greenValue == 255) {    

                        //pageListener.onPage1("GREEN");   
                        view.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressSx).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //view.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressSx).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (redValue == 255) {
                        //pageListener.onPage1("RED");    
                        view.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressDx).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    // new Connection().execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", "" + e.getMessage());
                }
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  // RELEASED
                //view.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressSx).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //view.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressDx).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

The code work, btu maybe beacause the second call to:

```
View view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doorsway_lay, container, false);
```

Is not referencing to the main view, the view that will be visible in the line

```
view.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressDx).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

will not show up in the GUI.
....in realty, it's not true that i can't figure out...

With the use of:

```
pageListener.onPage1("GREEN");
```

that is a function working in the main activity, passing a string and handling it,  i can get the main view only asking "findViewById" without referencing to a view, and  managing it with an if statement on the string, but this is not the way i want to handle that... I understand it is not the best way to do this...

Thank you in advance for reply and best regards to all of you.

Fin3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply, anyway i've found the solution... it looks like:

```
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // fragment not when container null
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // inflate view from layout
    View view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doorsway_lay, container, false);
    // get button reference
    /*
     * btnWrite = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btWrite); // set button
     * listener to trigger activity listener btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new
     * View.OnClickListener() {
     * 
     * @Override public void onClick(View v) {
     * pageListener.onPage1("Page 1 to"); } }); // update text TextView tv =
     * (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvText1); tv.setText(ptext);
     */
    //View imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.clickZones);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                try {
                    ImageView newView = ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.clickZones));
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) newView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
                    newView.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
                    float[] touchPoint = new float[] { event.getX(),
                            event.getY() };
                    inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);
                    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) touchPoint[0],
                            (int) touchPoint[1]);
                    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
                    if (greenValue == 255) {    

                        //pageListener.onPage1("GREEN");   //Questa funzione finisce nel Main_Activity
                        v.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressSx).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //view.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressSx).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (redValue == 255) {
                        //pageListener.onPage1("RED");    //Questa funzione finisce nel Main_Activity
                        v.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressDx).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    // new Connection().execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", "" + e.getMessage());
                }
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  // RELEASED
                v.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressSx).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                v.findViewById(R.id.imgChainPressDx).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

So, i'm not referencing to the specific view that causes the event in the onTouch overriding, but the whole view must be passed, the one given by the pageViewer, and then accessing the specific view with findViewById in the method.

Hope that this will help someone!

Good luck,

Fin3

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

- Is your fragment a SubClass of RegisterFragment?
- Standard mistake: Is 'fragment_doorsway_lay' written right?

(Sorry that I don't comment, but i have too less reputations...)